# Values outputting both NaN and "invalid date" and the correct values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This function takes arguments {values} and is supposed to calculate a result and set the state of it (in ReactJS). setResult() does not output anything to the console, however, both console.logs output Nan, invalid date, crash my React application and *then* output the correct values.

```
  const [calcResult, setResult] = useState();


  const calculator = (values) => {
    let resultSeconds = (values.fileSize*1000)/(values.downloadSpeed/8);
    let secondsPure = new Date(null);
    secondsPure.setSeconds(resultSeconds);
    console.log(secondsPure);
    console.log(resultSeconds);
    let result = secondsPure.toISOString().substr(11,8);
    setResult(result);
    console.log(result);
  };
```

For example, let's assume secondsPure = 80. The respective console.log(secondsPure) will print NaN and then, after the React applications crashes, it will print 80 to the console.

Examples for values:

```
downloadSpeed: "300"
fileSize: "3"
```

Comment: What are you expecting `new Date(null)` to give you? Also, please show example inputs and outputs.

Comment: I've added an example. new Date(null) is called to prepare a container for ```let result = secondsPure.toISOString().substr(11,8);
```

Comment: So we need an example of `values` because what's most likely happening is that `values.downloadSpeed` is 0, or a string, or something that is causing `resultSeconds` to be `NaN`, which would cause `secondsPure` to be `Invalid Date`.

Comment: I've added an example of ```values```, thanks for helping! :)

Comment: With those values, it works (outside of the react context): https://jsfiddle.net/73s8tx5y/

Answer (score 1):

setState is async fucntion which means when you do something like this

```
   const [result , setResult]=useState(null)
   const calculator = (values) => {
       setResult(result);
       console.log(result);//this will output null because setResult call is not done yet 
//when setResult  finishes you component reloads and only then you can get the new value 
   };
```

if you want to get the updated value you need to use `useEffect`and set `result`  as dependency

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(result)
  }, [result])
```